# How do I compare 2 XMM registers (SSE) and test for equality to break out of loop?

Tags: assembly, compare, sse, sse2

After using the assembly instruction:

pcmpeqd    xmm2, xmm7

The result in resgister xmm2 = 00000000 00000000 FFFFFFFF 00000000

The result is correct. Unfortunately the comparison sets no flags that can be tested to break out of the loop. Also any one of the 4 dwords can have all their bits set, not just the example given here. Do I have to load each one of the 4 dwords into a general purpose register to test again? Or is there a quicker way to do it?

Comment: Hi, the post maybe your first post which gives to me to review. I'm not familiar with register, but for stackoverflow, question hope a clear error scene. You can attempt your thinking and give a clear question is welcome.

Comment: You can use [`pmovmskb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb) to extract the upper bits of each byte into a register then use `test` to check if any or all bits are set. With SSE4.1 you can also try [`ptest`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest)

Comment: Note that you need to decide what the break condition is, i.e. "all equal" or "any equal".

Comment: I want to mark the response from chtz as helpful as his suggestion was exactly what I was looking for and it solved my problem! However, there is no green check mark to the left of the response that I can select to show as answered...

Comment: The above are just comments, not answers. You can write up the solution as a fully fledged answer and accept it, or invite chtz to do the same.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that Paul R. Thanks anyway. I will put up the solution after 48 hours since posting the question as I can only do so once that time has elapsed. :)